# Offset/change all row numbers in formulas in selected cells using macro in excel

Tags: excel, row, formula, offset, vba

I have a large number of helper rows taking information from a different sheet using a simple `sum` function:

```
=SUM('HIS-WOT'!J36,'HIS-WOT'!J82,'HIS-WOT'!J128)
```

Is there a macro out there that will allow me to change/offset all the row numbers in a number of selected cells by an equal amount (i.e. **221**) to get a formula such as:

```
=SUM('HIS-WOT'!J257,'HIS-WOT'!J333,'HIS-WOT'!J349)
```

The amount with which I need to change the various row numbers varies, so the macro would need to have a dialogue box allowing the user to choose by how much the user wants to increase or decrease row numbers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give create a dummy sheet to copy the formulas over, I liked your question!

```
Sub test()

    Dim nbr As Long, cel As Range, cels As Range, sh As Worksheet
    Set cels = Selection

    nbr = CLng(InputBox("Enter offset:"))

    Set sh = Worksheets.Add

    For Each cel In cels

        If cel.HasFormula Then

            sh.Cells(cel.Row + nbr, cel.Column).FormulaR1C1 = cel.FormulaR1C1
            cel.Formula = sh.Cells(cel.Row + nbr, cel.Column).Formula

        End If

    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        sh.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm! That saved me about 8 hours of work! Thanks a million!